# gpsd on CentOS 7 not working after yum install

Tags: centos, gpsd

I've installed gpsd 3.10 (also tried 3.16) on CentOS 7 Minimal (yum install gpsd). The following dependencies have been pulled in as well: bluez-libs, gpsd-libs, libusbx. It seems to start up fine automatically as a service, however, if I run it from the command line, it produces no output. Even running "gpsd -h" produces no help output at all. Seems like something pretty fundamental, so I'm trying to figure out if there's a missing dependency or other environment setup that I'm missing.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to the fact that "somehow" gpsd got installed under SE Linux.  Here's a link with further details: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-gpsd_selinux/

From what I recall, the following command enabled gpsd to work:

```
semanage permissive -a gpsd_t
```

I've subsequently installed gpsd on other machines and didn't encounter this issue.